# Is there the possibility to write many times a value in definite list of file1.nb?

Tags: export, files-and-directories

The commands

```
testData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1, 1}];
Export["C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\1\\file1.nb", testData];
```

write the “testData” (value generated by Notebook) into a list of the file1.nb.

If the Notebook is started again the previous content in the file1.nb is deleted and new “testData” value is written in a list.

Is there the possibility to write many times in a list of file1.nb a value (which generated by Notebook) without deleting of previous content of a list in the file1.nb?

Comment: You are making life difficult for yourself by using *Mathematica* notebook format files.  How about `Put` (`RandomReal[] >> file1.txt`) and `PutAppend` (`RandomReal[] >>> file1.txt`) if you are not committed to this format.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `PutAppend`? Something like this should give you the desired result:

```
testData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1, 1}];
OpenAppend["C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\1\\file1.nb", testData];
```

Consult the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PutAppend.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat by first importing the data and putting them in a list and when you are finished then you join the list with `Join`. it could look like this:

```
prevData = Import["C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\1\\file1.nb"];
testData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1, 1}];
TestDate = Join[prevData, testData];
Export["C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\1\\file1.nb", testData];
```

Comment: Thank you! However, the result is not an elegant list {R1,R2, ..Rn}.

Comment: Did you actually try this?  The typos suggest not. Importing a notebook file results in a `Notebook` expression in `prevData` which is not easily joined with the list in `testData`.